# How do I put a table beside a figure?

Tags: tables, floats

I want to put a table beside a figure. How do I do this? The closest I've gotten is this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Systematic uncertainty in equipment}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
        Torque &  $\pm 0.05\%$\\
        \hline
        Wind velocity & $\pm 0.1\%$ \\ 
        \hline
        Air density & $\pm 0.3 \%$ \\
        \hline
        RPM & $\pm 3$ \\
        \hline
        Current & $\pm 0.05\%$ \\
        \hline
        Voltage & $\pm 0.05 \%$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:Windtunneluncertanty}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{bilder/testrig.jpg}
    \caption{Testrig for the wind turbine} % kanskje endres
    \label{fig:testrig}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

see, if the following solution can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo,       % in real document remove this option
           ]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}    % added for figure/table caption
\usepackage{tabularx}   % 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
    \hline
        Torque &  $\pm 0.05\%$\\
        \hline
        Wind velocity & $\pm 0.1\%$ \\
        \hline
        Air density & $\pm 0.3 \%$ \\
        \hline
        RPM & $\pm 3$ \\
        \hline
        Current & $\pm 0.05\%$ \\
        \hline
        Voltage & $\pm 0.05 \%$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{bilder/testrig.jpg}     \\
\caption{Systematic uncertainty in equipment}
\label{tab:Windtunneluncertanty}
    &
    \captionof{figure}{Testrig for the wind turbine} % kanskje endres
    \label{fig:testrig}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use two `\minipage`s and place the floats inside using the `[H]` specifier from the `float` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}    
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
        Torque &  $\pm 0.05\%$\\
        \hline
        Wind velocity & $\pm 0.1\%$ \\ 
        \hline
        Air density & $\pm 0.3 \%$ \\
        \hline
        RPM & $\pm 3$ \\
        \hline
        Current & $\pm 0.05\%$ \\
        \hline
        Voltage & $\pm 0.05 \%$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:Windtunneluncertanty}
    \caption{Systematic uncertainty in equipment}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Testrig for the wind turbine} % kanskje endres
    \label{fig:testrig}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I realize that [H] is equivalent to using a minipage, but putting a "float" inside a minipage just encourages had habits.  Then again, the same can be said for [H] in general.